# How to convert a hardware bitmap into to a software bitmap in Android?

Tags: android

Many operations don't work on Hardware bitmaps in Android. What is the easiest way to convert the hardware bitmap into a non-hardware bitmap?

Comment: It is a bit different, but still related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58315279/6350039 I needed to make a screenshot of a view into software bitmap and linked answer helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use bitmap.copy()

```
Bitmap softwareBitmap = hardwareBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
```

*Performance Note: the copy takes about 6 milliseconds for a 1080 X 2280 bitmap on a pixel 4*

Comment: It throws IllegalArgumentException.